# UWP event override base.onnavigatedto

Tags: overriding, win-universal-app

I have a simple question that whenever I override a event like 
`OnNavigatedTo()` or `OnApplytemplate()`, there is a line written `base.Onnavigatedto()` or `base.something....`

What does that line of code do? i usually remove that line, should i keep it or remove it ? thankyou

Comment: I suggest you do _not_ remove the line since you don't know what logic the base class's virtual method has implemented.  There are [some questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9623966/815938) on SO already, and they explain better.

Comment: thanksyou that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Page it by default inherits from the Page base class. That class also has an implementation of OnNavigatedTo. Calling base.OnNavigatedTo calls the base classes implementation.

In general when inheriting from a base class you want to extend it's functionality by adding to it. So you'd run the original implementation and then add your own code.

By removing it you are basically saying: I want to change the behavior to the one I specify.

In general it's good practice to keep it in there as you likely don't know what the base class is doing there and it might break stuff (or just be inconsequential if the base class merely provides it as an integration point to be overridden).

As an example:

You might want to log each time someone navigates to a new page. Instead of putting that code in each page you could first create a page we might call LoggingPage and override OnNavigatedTo there to do the logging. Then we could make all our other pages inherit from that page and get logging for free. If however on one of those pages you override OnNavigatedTo and remove the base-call that page would no longer do the logging as the base class implementation is no longer getting called.

Comment: perfect answer, with perfect clarification, thanks a lot :)